# How to set the inline image opaque in QtConsole3?

Tags: python, python-3.4, qtconsole

I run `QtConsole3` with thw following command:

```
ipython3 qtconsole --cache-size=4000 --matplotlib=inline --colors=Linux
```

And plot a figure with following lines:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1024) * 4 * np.pi

In [4]: y = np.sin(x) / x

In [5]: plt.plot(x, y)
```

However, the axis and the labels in the figure are disappeared because the inline figure is transparent and the background is black.
[image]

**So how to run `QtConsole` with some extra arguments such that the inline figure would display proper?**

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use LightBG colors instead of Linux?

Comment: @PeterBrittain I just want to try^_^

Answer (score 1):

You could change your rcparams programatically before plotting

```
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = "(1, 1, 1)"
```

or in your matplotlibrc file; or you could be explicit:

```
fig = figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
fig
```